# Compile-time error building a simple partial array class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, private, member

I'm having trouble getting my Partial Arrays class to compile. In one of my member functions I call for a previous member function and get the error "member reference base type 'ITEM_TYPE [255]' is not a structure or union".

I'm not entirely sure that my member variable declarations are up to snuff, as this is my first time dealing with arrays in C++.

Here is my header:

```
#ifndef PARTIALARRAY_H
#define PARTIALARRAY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
typedef int ITEM_TYPE;
ITEM_TYPE const MAX = 255;

class PartialArray
{
public:
    //-----------------------------------------ctors:-----------------------------------------
    PartialArray();
    PartialArray(ITEM_TYPE MAX, int numUsed);

    //-----------------------------------------member functions:-----------------------------------------
    void PrintArray(int a[], int numUsed);
    int Search(int a[], int numUsed, ITEM_TYPE key);
    int Append(ITEM_TYPE appendMe);
    int ShiftRight(int shiftHere);
    int ShiftLeft(int shiftHere);
    int InsertBefore(ITEM_TYPE insertThis, int insertHere);
    int InsertAfter(ITEM_TYPE insertThis, int insertHere);
    int Delete(int deleteHere);
    string ErrorDescr(int failCode);

private:
    //-----------------------------------------member vars:-----------------------------------------
    ITEM_TYPE a[MAX];
    int numUsed;
};

#endif // PARTIALARRAY_H
```

And my class declaration (NOTE: the error function and return values are not complete, so those can be ignored):

```
#include "partialarray.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

//-----------------------------------------ctors:-----------------------------------------
PartialArray::PartialArray()
{
    numUsed=0;
}

PartialArray::PartialArray(ITEM_TYPE MAX, int numUsed)
{
    numUsed = MAX;
}

//-----------------------------------------member functions:-----------------------------------------
//Prints the array up to its last used element
void PartialArray::PrintArray(ITEM_TYPE a[], int numUsed)
{
    for(int i=0; i<numUsed; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//Searches the array for a particular value and returns the index at which the value first appears
int PartialArray::Search(ITEM_TYPE a[], int numUsed, ITEM_TYPE key)
{
    for(int i=0; i<numUsed; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==key)
        {
            return i;
            break;
        }
        else
            ;
    }
    return -1; //placeholder for error
}

//Takes a number and appends it to the end of the array after the last interesting element
int PartialArray::Append(ITEM_TYPE appendMe)
{
    if(a[numUsed==0])
        a[numUsed] = appendMe;
    else
        return 0; //placeholder for error
    return 1; //placeholder for error
}

//Shifts all elements of the array to the right starting at a particular index
int PartialArray::ShiftRight(int shiftHere)
{
    ITEM_TYPE save = a[numUsed-1];
    for(int i=numUsed; i>=shiftHere; i--)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    a[0] = save;
    return 1; //error placeholder
}

//Shifts all elements of the array to the left starting at a particular index
int PartialArray::ShiftLeft(int shiftHere)
{
    ITEM_TYPE save = a[0];
    for(int i=shiftHere; i<numUsed; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i+1];
    }
    a[numUsed-1] = save;
    return 1; //error placeholder
}

//Takes a number and a position and inserts the number at that position in the array shifting the elements to the right
int PartialArray::InsertBefore(ITEM_TYPE insertThis, int insertHere)
{
    a.ShiftRight(insertHere);
    a[insertHere] = insertThis;
    return 1; //error placeholder
}

//Takes a number and a position and inserts the number at that position in the array shifting the elements to the left
int PartialArray::InsertAfter(ITEM_TYPE insertThis, int insertHere)
{
    a.ShiftLeft(insertHere);
    a[insertHere] = insertThis;
    return 1; //error placeholder
}

//Takes a position and removes that item from the array, shifting all the elements to the left
int PartialArray::Delete(int deleteHere)
{
    a[deleteHere] = 0;
    a.ShiftLeft(deleteHere);
    return 1; //error placeholder
}

string PartialArray::ErrorDescr(int failCode)
{
    switch(failCode)
    {
    case 1:
        return "ERROR: etc";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "ERROR: etc";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "ERROR: etc";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "ERROR: etc";
        break;
    case 5:
        return "ERROR: etc";
        break;
    default:
        return "ERROR: etc";
        break;
    }
}
```

I have previously built a Rationals class, and I felt solid on that material, but doing something similar with arrays has proven to be a major headache. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: _`a.ShiftRight(insertHere);`_ An array doesn't have a `ShiftRight()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code seems ok. However, `a` is a C-style array, and thus has no member functions.

Thus, the following lines are incorrect:

```
a.ShiftRight(insertHere);
...
a.ShiftLeft(insertHere);
```

As you try to use this array with a syntax meaningul only for struct or class variables, the compiler issues here the error message you observe: `"member reference base type 'ITEM_TYPE [255]' is not a structure or union"`

Comment: I am trying to call my ShiftRight member function on my private member variable a[MAX]. Is there a way to do that without repeating the code from that function? Thanks!

Comment: @Jac7k Just `ShiftRight(insertHere);` should be enough here.

Comment: Great! That at least got it to compile; now off to debug.